# TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'promiseLibrary'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose-schema

I'm getting the following error:

> (node:5245) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to
>   search for 'promiseLibrary' in TweeterSearch
>
> (node:5245) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections
>   are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled
>   will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code

This is my config.js file

```
   // general configuration
   var mongoose = require('mongoose');
   var config = {
   db_host: 'mongodb://localhost',
   db_name: 'TweeterSearch',
   db_collection_twitter: 'Tweets',
   db_debug: 0,

   // Twitter Harvester Schema API 1.1
   tw_harvest_schema_11: {
   contributors : mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
   coordinates: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
   created_at: Date,
   current_user_retweet : mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
   entities: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
   favorited : Boolean,
   geo : mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
   id: Number,
   id_str : String,
   in_reply_to_screen_name : String,
   in_reply_to_status_id : Number,
   in_reply_to_status_id_str: String,
   in_reply_to_user_id : Number,
   in_reply_to_user_id_str : String,
   place : mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
   possibly_sensitive : Boolean,
   scopes : mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
   retweet_count : Number,
   retweeted_status: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
   retweeted : Boolean,
   source: String,
   text : String,
truncated : Boolean,
user : mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
withheld_copyright :  Boolean,
withheld_in_countries : mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
withheld_scope : String,
  },
  }

 module.exports = config;
```

What changes should I make in order for my app.js to work?